# Select value using jQuery in same order with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multiselect dropdown.

```
<select class="select2" multiselect>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

I want to select multiselect on page ready so I tried below code to achieve. But every time I got result in sorted form. But I want selected items in same order.

```
$('.select2').select2();


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.select2').val(['B','E','A']).trigger('change');

    $("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");
    });

})
```

Note: when I select manually, it's working fine. But on trigger, it's not working

Comment: You may want to change `$(".select").select2();` to `$(".select2").select2();` for starters

Comment: that was a typo mistake